# Javascript interactive card being glitchy

Tags: javascript

I made an interactive card.  When grabbing the object with the mouse and moving it, it flies right back to where it was.  Then it will "stick" to the mouse cursor.  click to release.  I would like a smoother click and drag.  The rest of the card works fine.  Thanks for the help in advance.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

```
<title>Seasonal Greetings</title>

<style>

    canvas {
        border: #333 10px solid;
        background-image: url(images/springBackground.png);

    }
    #mydiv {
        position: absolute;
        z-index: 10;
        text-align: center;
    }
    h1 {
        color: #6433af;
        font: georgia;
    }
    p {
        color: #f442b0;
        font: arial;
    }



</style>
```

## Thinking of You Greetings

```
    <p>Drag the flower into the flowerpot. Click to release.</p>
    <p>When finished, press the "END" key (or the "S" key on iMac)</p>

    <div id="mydiv">
      <img src="images/flower.png" alt="flower" style="width:150px;height:200px;">
    </div>

        <canvas id="canvas" width="630px" height="430px"></canvas>
        <a href="https://www.freepik.com/free-photos-vectors/background">Background vector created by Freepik</a>

        <script>
    //Make the DIV element draggagle:
    dragElement(document.getElementById(("mydiv")));

    function dragElement(elmnt) {
      var pos1 = 0, pos2 = 0, pos3 = 0, pos4 = 0;
      if (document.getElementById(elmnt.id + "header")) {
        /* if present, the header is where you move the DIV from:*/
        document.getElementById(elmnt.id + "header").onmousedown = dragMouseDown;
      } else {
        /* otherwise, move the DIV from anywhere inside the DIV:*/
        elmnt.onmousedown = dragMouseDown;
      }

      function dragMouseDown(e) {
        e = e || window.event;
        // get the mouse cursor position at startup:
        pos3 = e.clientX;
        pos4 = e.clientY;
        document.onmouseup = closeDragElement;
        // call a function whenever the cursor moves:
        document.onmousemove = elementDrag;
      }

      function elementDrag(e) {
        e = e || window.event;
        // calculate the new cursor position:
        pos1 = pos3 - e.clientX;
        pos2 = pos4 - e.clientY;
        pos3 = e.clientX;
        pos4 = e.clientY;
        // set the element's new position:
        elmnt.style.top = (elmnt.offsetTop - pos2) + "px";
        elmnt.style.left = (elmnt.offsetLeft - pos1) + "px";
      }

      function closeDragElement() {
        /* stop moving when mouse button is released:*/
        document.onmouseup = null;
        document.onmousemove = null;
      }
    }
```

```
<script>

    //end key
    window.addEventListener("keydown", checkKeyPressed, false);
    function checkKeyPressed(e) {
        if(e.keyCode == "83" || e.keyCode == "35") {
            ctx.font = "bold Italic 18px Arial";
            ctx.fillStyle = "#a142f4";
            ctx.fillText("Thinking of you...", 320, 280);
            ctx.fillText("Each new blossom", 320, 320);
            ctx.fillText("brings a new day.", 320, 350);
            ctx.fillText("Enjoy your day, Sherri", 320, 390);
        }
        e.preventDefault();
    }

    var ctx = document.querySelector("canvas").getContext("2d"),
    dashLen = 220, dashOffset = dashLen, speed = 5,
    txt = "Happy Spring", x = 150, i = 0;


    ctx.font = "50px Georgia, cursive, sans-serif"; 
    ctx.lineWidth = 5; ctx.lineJoin = "round"; ctx.globalAlpha = 2/3;
    ctx.strokeStyle = ctx.fillStyle = "#ffcc00";

    (function loop() {
      ctx.clearRect(x, 0, 60, 150);
      ctx.setLineDash([dashLen - dashOffset, dashOffset - speed]); // create a long dash mask
      dashOffset -= speed;                                         // reduce dash length
      ctx.strokeText(txt[i], x, 200);                               // stroke letter

      if (dashOffset > 0) requestAnimationFrame(loop);             // animate
      else {
        ctx.fillText(txt[i], x, 200);                               // fill final letter
        dashOffset = dashLen;                                      // prep next char
        x += ctx.measureText(txt[i++]).width + ctx.lineWidth * Math.random();
        ctx.setTransform(1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 3 * Math.random());        // random y-delta
        ctx.rotate(Math.random() * 0.005);                         // random rotation
        if (i < txt.length) requestAnimationFrame(loop); checkKeyPressed();
      }
    })();

    </script>
```

[springbackground.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yW2Yx.png)
[flower.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G2wBp.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To make it work, append this to the bottom of your `dragElement` function:

```
elmnt.ondragstart = function() {
    return false;
};
```

This will cancel browser's default behaviour with drag 'n drop for images.